# PHP Sql code not running

Tags: php, sql

Trying to get code to connect to SQL database and authenticate.

It keeps returning "Invalid username/password combination."

Here is the code :

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli( $hn, $un,$pw, $db);
if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    $un_temp= sanitize($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp= sanitize($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);
    else{
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        $salt1 = "qm&h*";
        $salt2 = "pg!@";
        $token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

        if ($token == $row[3]) echo "$row[0] $row[1] : 
            Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
            else die("Invalid username/password combination");
    }
} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Please enter your username and password");
}

$connection->close();

function sanitize($var) {
    $value = stripslashes($var);
    $value = strip_tags($var);
    $value = htmlentities($var);
    return $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure the values of $hn, $un, $pw and $db are correct.

Comment: Pull out the salt and the hash and just see what the return is you get back from the database.  That error message is your error message in the `if: else: die` code.  See is the values you are getting back from the database are valid.  And after you do that you need a better authentication/security system.  Don't roll your own encryption.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). In addition, make sure you [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html).

Comment: Your `sanitize` function does nothing to stop you from being SQL injected. Use parameterized queries. Also why not hash before sending query and have SQL validate the password with the username?

Comment: Why would you pass more than the completed connection around as a variable?